# I need to create array of a class in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I am trying to set the day from my `Timechannel` class and I tried every possible way to create an array of my `Daytable` class.

I am new at typescript but in C# works very nice. Need some guide to make this work. It's very simplify part of the code.

```
class Daytable {
    public Day: string = '';
}

class Timechannel  {
    private _signalname: string = '';
    private _Daytable: Array<Daytable> = new Array<Daytable>(5)

    get DayTables() {
        return this._Daytable;
    }

    set DayTables(value: Array<Daytable>) {
        this._Daytable= value;
    }


    get signalName() {
        return this._signalname;
    }

    set signalName(value: string) {
        this._signalname = value; 

        this._Daytable[0].Day = this._signalname + 'Monday';
        .
        .
        .
        .
        .
        this._Daytable[5].Day = this._signalname + 'Friday';

    }
}
```

Comment: What doesn't work? Do you get an type error? A runtime error? If so on which line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you're problem may be here:

```
new Array<Daytable>(5)
```

Remember that typescript type don't exist at runtime, only compile time. This means that the above line is turned into this javascript:

```
new Array(5)
```

This creates an array of 5 empty items.

If you intended to have an instead of `Daytable` in each of those 5 spots, you need to actually call the constructor 5 times.

```
private _Daytable: Array<Daytable> = [
    new Daytable(),
    new Daytable(),
    new Daytable(),
    new Daytable(),
    new Daytable(),
]
```

---

Also, [avoid using the Array constructor](https://coderwall.com/p/h4xm0w/why-never-use-new-array-in-javascript). It doesn't usually do what you expect. Use array literals instead `[1,2,3]`.

Comment: this one solved the problem private                  _Daytable: Array<Daytable> = [
    new Daytable(), 
    new Daytable(),
    new Daytable(),
    new Daytable(),
    new Daytable(),
]

Comment: Thank you Alex, You saved me a lot of jobs.